# PHP Ajax load file with jQuery inside file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am loading a PHP file using Ajax below which works great except I want to be able to load some javascrip/jQuery items within that file to function on the main index page.

```
       prices();    
       function prices()
        {
            $.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "inc/load_prices.php",
               cache: false,
               success: function(response){
                  $("#prices").hide().html(response).fadeIn(500);
                }
           });
        }
    setInterval(prices, 600000);
```

Inside load_prices.php I have some stock ticker type output which works fine outside the AJAX call using the below.  However when loading the contact via AJAX it wont trigger the webticker.min.js file and wont render properly.

```
<!-- If loading this without AJAX the ticker works fine -->    
<script src="js/jquery.webticker.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#ticker").webTicker({ 
                duplicate:true,
                hoverpause:false,
            }); 
        </script>
```

How do I allow the contents of the prices() AJAX function to render properly when needed to reference jQuery?

Comment: How do `#prices` , `#ticker` elements affect each other? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate? What is `.webTicker()` ?

Comment: #prices is just <div id="prices"></> to place the response. #ticker lives inside load_prices.php which is being called by AJAX but this is the area which does not work.  I beleive its the nature of AJAX not referencing the jQuery items since the main index page is already loaded and DOM is set?

Comment: `response` includes `<script>` tags?

Comment: At the moment the response includes NO scripts tags.  load_prices.php includes updated pricing numbers.  The intent is to have AJAX poll load_prices.php to update the pricing.  #ticker adds a scrolling effect like a stock ticker does.  Hoping to update pricing without loading the entire page.

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: I think your answer was on the right track.  Looks like you removed it though.  $.getScript is likely what I'm missing.  Feel free to add the answer back if you want

Comment: Un-deleted Answer. Does using `$.getScript()` resolve Question?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but in load_prices.php

`src="../js/jquery.webticker.min.js"`

as both are in different directory

Answer (score 0):

If interpret Question correctly, use `$.getScript()` to load `webticker.min.js` once. Not certain what purpose is of calling `.webTicker()` every `600000` ms?

```
$.getScript("js/jquery.webticker.min.js")
.then(function() {
  $("#ticker")
  .webTicker({ 
    duplicate:true,
    hoverpause:false
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I dont need to call `.webTicker()` every 60000ms.  I just need to refresh the data found in `inc/load_prices.php` that often.  I tried the above but that didn't seem to work.  Loads the pricing but webticker does not function properly.

Comment: What is issue with approach at Question which requests `inc/load_prices.php`?